# Regex Query To seperate and extract two different set from a string?

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract two seperate information from a string.

For example,

```
$string = 'int(5)';
//Now I need "int" and the text inside the brackets "5" seperately;
$datatype = ?
$varlength = ?
```

How to extract those information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex

`^([a-z]+)\(([0-9]+)\)$`

```
if (preg_match('~^([a-z]+)\(([0-9]+)\)$~i', 'int(5)', $matches)) {
  $datatype  = $matches[1]; // int
  $varlength = $matches[2]; // 5
}
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to match more than just a number in the brackets, expand it as necessary:

```
^([a-z]+)\(([0-9a-zA-Z, ]+)\)$ // numbers, letters, comma or space
^([a-z]+)\(([^)]+)\)$          // anything but a closing bracket
```

Comment: Wow, thanks this just works great. But, it is not guaranteed that the text inside bracket is number, can be something like `enum(1,a)`, in this case I want `1,a`

Comment: @mrN, It should match `varchar(50)` now

Comment: Sorry about the typpo. Thanks, Starx!

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
list($datatype, $varlength) = explode('(', trim($string, ')'));
```

This only works if there can be only one opening bracket.

**Reference:** [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php), [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Answer (score 1):

In the case. you want to match anything inside the brackets, use this

```
preg_match('/^([a-z]+)\(([a-zA-Z0-9\,]+)\)$/', 'enum(1,a)' , $matches);
print_r($matches);
```